# is the Camera API useful to scale images?

Tags: android, image, cordova, cordova-plugins

My Cordova app (for Android) is sent image URI's from the device's photo gallery and I then intend to process them -- sizing, changing quality, etc.

Currently, I am able to present the image in an app view, but it takes long to load and sometimes the image is rotated.

Is it a common use case to rely on the Camera api for scaling and other image handling in this case? My experiments so far seem only to confirm the Camera API is useful to elicit selections from the user, whereas I would supply it with a URI programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about the Cordova, But I recently worked with Camera2 API which is predecessor of Camera API in Android.

As I think, Camera API is there to present you with an output with relative to what options/ features you ask from the Camera API. 
There is a way to get image in RAW format(very large) and other formats as well(.jpg is one option that I know) with different sizes and quality. And you can convert them into any other format (From here inwards you can use anything to deal with the images), apply filters ect.

But when it comes to displaying the images, the BitMap data type is used, Yes, if the image is large it takes time to load the image.

Obviously if you are loading it from the disk, it takes time, Generally, But you can mitigate this by using caching mechanisms, and also providing loading bars so that user as a usability improvement.

To change the quality and the  size there is API provided in [BitMapFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html). There is a very good tutorial specifially for your area that you are looking into, which has the use of BitMapFactory and other related material. Have a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) as well.

Sometimes the app tend crash because of the out or Memory issue, You can use `android:largeHeap="true"` in your Manifest file. Which will allocate you a larger heap to work with, This is specifically for image processing like apps, which requires larger memory.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, but my interest is specifically in Cordova, not least because I can program it in Javascript.